# set UIBarButtonItem style while a modal view is shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While showing a modal view I change the style of a UIBarButtonItem in the view controller beneath.

Though, when dismissing the modal view the UIBarButtonItem does not reflect the set style. Do I need to send some refresh message?

This is happening in the simulator. If the device behaves the same, I don't know.

Comment: A code block would help us, where do you push the modal view controller and set the UIBarButtonItem?  Do you add it to the navigationItem (if it's a UINavigationController?) or is it on a Toolbar?

Comment: A refresh method would be something like:

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

But as Malaxeur said, we need code...

Comment: well, I have a ViewController containing the UIBarButtonItem. From this ViewController I instantiate another ViewController, pass self as a custom delegate and present it modally. While presented I call a method on the delegate (the initial ViewController) in which the style of the UIBarButton is changed. Then I dismiss the modal vewController and the UIBarButtonItem's style is not reflected in it's appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing it seems that changes to a UIBarButtonItem in general are not propagated if it is not visible (either hidden by eg a modal view or just not on screen).

So for now my workaround is just to make sure the UIBarButtonItem is visible when changing it.